# How to play single player in AI War: Fleet Command?

Tags: ai-war-fleet-command

Yesterday I bought AI War: Fleet Command and all its DLC. But when I start game I don't find the way to play in single player. The only button I could see is the host a multiplayer, and then disconnect all participants and play against the only two computer player.

It is possible to play in single player?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "Host New Campaign" button says it's for *1-8 players*

[image: (image of main menu)]

As I understand it *(I am still going through the tutorials)*, you are always against the two AI, no matter how many people are playing.

Comment: But you cannot play against (for example) 8 AI players?

Comment: @Killrazor: I don't think this is that sort of RTS - the game doesn't get harder by adding more AI, it gets harder by giving the AI more stuff to start with, and making it more aggressive.

Comment: @Killrazor With the way the game is designed, playing against 8 AI would be pretty much suicide due to how much AI progress you would acquire as well as not having the space needed to expand enough to start taking them down.  I believe the AI also gets smarter as well.